# rails what does ">" mean inside of the element of an assert_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, select, assert

In the book I'm using, there's a test with this lien of code

```
assert_select '.store .entry > img', 3
```

I get that it's looking for  tags in the html inside of class entry which is inside of class store. I don't know what the > means. In fact, this code fails the testing as it ends up with a return value of 0 instead of 3. However, if I remove the > and use this

```
assert_select '.store .entry img', 3
```

the program is able to find the 3 img elements. What does the ">" sign mean in this case? Also, why does it fail to find the img tags when that symbol is included as specified in the book, but it works when that symbol is removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FChild_selectors) means that only `img` elements which are direct children of the elements with class `entry` will be matched. Meaning this `img` will be matched:

```
<div class="store">
  <div class="entry">
    <img src=""/>
  </div>
</div>
```

But not this one:

```
<div class="store">
  <div class="entry">
    <p>
      <img src=""/>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

When you remove it, `img` elements in both examples will be found.

Comment: the way my code is structured, there img tag is wrapped by <a> tags. Would that make it no longer a direct child of class entry?  I basically have <div class="entry><a><img ....></a> ...more code</div>

Comment: Yes, direct child means no tags between the two.